# Autocomplete в Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Пытаюсь реализовать autocomplete. 
Код в xhtml файле:

```
<h:form>
    <p:panelGrid cellpadding="5" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel value="Login:" for="name"/>
        <p:autoComplete id="name" value="#{autoBean.user}" completeMethod="#{uB.completeUser}" var="user"
                        itemLabel="#{user.login}" itemValue="#{user}" converter="userConverter" dropdown="true" forceSelection="true"/>

        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{autoBean.aList}">
            <f:ajax execute="name" render="out"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:outputLabel id="out" value="#{autoBean.user.login}"/>
    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Код в Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="aB", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class AutoBean implements Serializable{
    private User user;
    private Locale locale;
    private List<User> users;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        user = new User();
        DAOImpl dao = new DAOImpl();
        users = dao.getAllUsers();
        locale = new Locale("ru");
    }

    public List<User> completeUser(String query) {

        List<User> filteredUsers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (User user : users) {
            if (user.getLogin().toLowerCase().startsWith(query)) {
                filteredUsers.add(user);
            }
        }

        // Сортировка пользователей в автодополнении
        filteredUsers.sort(new Comparator<User>() {
            public int compare(User s1, User s2) {
                return s1.getLogin().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getLogin());
            }
        });

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Класс `UserConverter`:

```
@FacesConverter("userConverter")
public class UserConverter implements Converter {    

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
        if(value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                AutoBean autoBean = (AutoBean) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("aB"); // NullPointerException
                return autoBean.getUsers().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid theme."));
            }
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object obj) {
        if(obj != null) {
            return String.valueOf(((User) obj).getLogin());
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Получаю `NullPointerException` на строке

```
AutoBean autoBean = (AutoBean) fc.getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("aB");
```

В дебаггере - `autoBean = null`. Перерыл всю документацию, причину найти не могу. Само автодополнение работает, список пользователей виден, ошибка возникает при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Приведённый код неконсистентен. `autoBean` или `aB`, что за `uB`? Класс AutoBean не компилируется, что за метод `autoBean.aList`? Попробуйте максимально упростить пример, удалив всю специфическую бизнес-логику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDoc к `ExternalContext.getApplicationMap()` сообщает, что

> Return a mutable Map representing the **application scope** attributes for
>   the current application

Т.е., метод даёт доступ только к компонентам с жизненным циклом `@ApplicationScoped`

В вашем случае следует использовать либо `ExternalContext.getSessionMap()`, т.к. компонент помечен как `@SessionScoped`, либо более универсальный `FacesContext.getELContext().getELResolver()`:

```
fc.getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(fc.getELContext(), null,"aB")
```